# How to iterate through json and add data in to array?

Tags: ios, json, loops, iteration

Here is how I iterate through my Json "data":

```
[myObject removeAllObjects];

NSDictionary *dic = jsonData[@"data"];

    for (NSArray *ar in dic) {

        [myObject addObject:ar];

}
```

Here is NSLog for myObject:

```
myObject: (
    23,
    22,
    21
)
```

**How can I iterate through all "data" (in 21,22,23 etc.) to add info about companies in to myObject array?**

My Json structure:

```
{
    "data": {
        "21": {
            "id": "21",
            "company_id": "17",
            "company_name": "Company 1",
            "logo_url": "http://www.company.com/1.png",
            "status": "2",
            "allow_name": "N",
            "allow_address": "N",
            "allow_email": "N",
            "allow_phone": "N",
            "allow_birthday": "N",
            "allow_gender": "N",
            "created": false
        },
        "22": {
            "id": "22",
            "company_id": "5",
            "company_name": "Company 2",
            "logo_url": "http://www.company.com/2.png",
            "status": "2",
            "allow_name": "N",
            "allow_address": "N",
            "allow_email": "N",
            "allow_phone": "N",
            "allow_birthday": "N",
            "allow_gender": "N",
            "created": false
        }
    },
    "success": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append the following sytax in your dictionary.

```
[valueForKey:@"company_name"]
```

Check the following tutorial: http://iosdevtips.co/post/80598241763/valueforkey-nsarray

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *aryData = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (int i=0; i<myObject.count; i++) {

        [aryData addObject:myObject[i]];
    }
```